# WordPress docker image. How to add NPM?

Tags: node.js, wordpress, docker, npm, docker-compose

I try to create my WordPress/Docker starter.
I have docker-compose.yml file and it's works.

```
version: '2'

services:
   db:
     image: mysql:5.7
     volumes:
       - db_data:/var/lib/mysql
     restart: always
     environment:
       MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: wordpress
       MYSQL_DATABASE: wordpress
       MYSQL_USER: wordpress
       MYSQL_PASSWORD: wordpress

   wordpress:
     depends_on:
       - db
     image: wordpress:latest
     ports:
       - "8000:80"
     restart: always
     environment:
       WORDPRESS_DB_HOST: db:3306
       WORDPRESS_DB_PASSWORD: wordpress
     volumes:
      - .app/wp-content/themes:/var/www/html/wp-content/themes
volumes:
    db_data:
```

In docker bash i received `npm command not found`. Where can i add node install?

Comment: Why do you want npm in the same container?

Comment: I just want to create package.json file in theme dir and run `npm install`

Comment: You're going to need a custom Dockerfile that installs NPM first then.

Comment: Ok, it's works. Thank you!
Dockerfile:
`FROM wordpress:latest`

Answer (score 0):

How about you run one command?

```
docker run -it --rm --name npm-compiler -v "$PWD":/usr/src/app -w /usr/src/app node:4 npm install
```

This will run node container and invoke `npm install` in it.

Comment: I am going to write my own dockerfile from wordpress official image and insert there an install command.